# What is the meaning of char (& test(...))[2]

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of the following declaration:

```
char (& test(...))[2];
```

I pasted it inside a function body as is and it compiles all right. I don't know what I can do with it but it passes the compilation.

I've encountered something similar in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/possible-for-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence/264088#264088)  answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the declaration of a function taking a variable argument list and returning a reference to an array of 2 `char`.

Note that if define a function like this the parameters are inaccessible (via standard means) as the `<cstdarg>` macros require a variable argument list to follow a named parameter.

If you like, you can defined a function with this declaration and return a reference to suitable array. You can call it with any parameters, subject to the restrictions for `...` parameters which include the restrictions that passing non-POD class types causes undefined behaviour.

E.g.

```
namespace
{
    char samplearray[2];
}

char (& test(...))[2]
{
    return samplearray;
}
```

Comment: variables defined in anonymous namespace cannot be 'extern'ed outside the file where the namespace resides.

Answer (score 1):

> Declare **test** as a vararg function returning a reference to an array of 2 `char`s

A useful site for de-mangling such declarations is [cdecl: C gibberish <-> English](http://cdecl.org/) (although it doesn't understand varargs and is C oriented rather than C++).

Comment: Wow that's a funny site. I can just sit and hit "refresh" for hours :)

Comment: @FireAphis that's when you know it's time to seek professional help ;o)